# Is there a function to get the standard deviation of a dataset after interpolation?

Tags: python, interpolation, data-analysis, standard-deviation

I interpolated a dataset as follow:

```
y = [-2.35771490e-04, -2.04672372e-04,  5.40550849e-06, -3.26933980e-04,
       -4.31306957e-04, -4.06928662e-04, -7.50889655e-04, -1.03669983e-03,
       -5.28464040e-04, -5.01935670e-04, -8.09657243e-04, -4.21891416e-04,
       -1.35441615e-04, -3.46855608e-04, -2.90791620e-04, -8.19357356e-05,
       -2.58070932e-04, -1.58262175e-04,  1.32105126e-04,  2.42572582e-05,
        9.88706879e-05]

x = [175., 165., 155., 145., 135., 125., 115., 105.,  95.,  85.,  75.,
    65.,  55.,  45.,  35.,  25.,  15.,   5.,  -5., -15., -25.]

f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
x_new = np.arange(-25,175, 5)
y_interp = f(x_new))
```

However, I'd like to know if it's possible to calculate the standard deviation for each new element in y_interp.
The errors for elements in y are:

```
err = [0.00012969551729667857, 0.00014864077922340332, 0.00010732361332456688, 8.95365810198269e-05, 8.559972679579093e-05, 0.00010669277818690999, 6.880710200343582e-05, 9.249378243164652e-05, 9.885179214527947e-05, 8.352246348207366e-05, 6.586538652949116e-05, 7.428127049298688e-05, 6.506191339534108e-05, 7.166116284348538e-05, 6.379032268503384e-05, 7.101008284147194e-05, 6.0593495968463165e-05, 4.699920194672463e-05, 5.854938570487613e-05, 7.140629409894438e-05, 9.66241238445066e-05]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you call *standard deviation for each element*? I only know what the standard deviation is for a data set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many ways in python to calculate the standard deviation! for example, you could use the [numpy.std()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) function:

```
std_of_y_interp = np.std(y_interp)
```

If you want to know the standard deviation for each new element in y_interp, you have to call this function each time a new element is added to y_interp

Comment: Thanks. By adding this line, now it's working: `err.append(np.std(f(x_new)))`